# AWS: Spot instance - I do not care where

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way in which I can request a Spot Instance at the lowest price anywhere in the world? I.e. I do not care which region/data center the machine is in.

If not: Is there a way to get the history of prices for the whole world and not just for a single region?

Answer (score 2):

Amazon CloudFront, Amazon Route 53 and Amazon IAM are global services. All other services (including Amazon EC2) operate within Regions. Each region is independent, with their own [endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html). Therefore, **it is not possible to obtain information from multiple regions with a single API call**.

Nor is there a capability to launch an Amazon EC2 Spot Instance in any region. The API call to launch a Spot Instance must be sent to the endpoint of a region, and the resources will only be launched in that region.  This is by design, because **each Region is independent**.

You will need to:

- Retrieve prices from each region individually
- Decide for yourself (eg programmatically) where you wish to create resources
- Send the request to that specific region

Answer (score 0):

SPOT instance pricing fluctuate in matter of hour and by region, so there is no single API call to grab all the info. Depends how you provision spot instance, historical price of SPOT instance has little use with introduction of Spot Fleet.

If you just want to get the worldwide pricelist for non-spot instance offer, then you should look into 
[AWS price list API](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-price-list-api/) and write your own process to parsed multiple region offer.